# How can I get the current color profile's file name (the icc file name) in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, opengl, color-profile

I want to know what color profile is being used for a given screen to keep a record.
Basically I am using OpenGL on MacOSX in mixed Objective-C/cocoa and C app and render some geometric shapes that are displayed on projectors, or CRTs or LCDs and since the calibration is very important, I need to keep a record of what color profile was being used at each time,

Any way to get the current profile name, either using Objective-c frameworks, or OpenGL or any other means, shell scripts, apple scripts ....